# Optimize query and use of table "tblA" inner join with "tblA" 

Tags: sql-server

I have seen one sql query, which is like,

```
SELECT B.SubscriptionID
FROM 
 tblA A1
inner JOIN  tblA A2 ON A1.AcctServiceID = A2.AcctServiceID  
INNER JOIN  tblB B ON A2.ServiceID = B.ServiceID
INNER JOIN  tblC C ON B.SubscriptionID = C.SubscriptionID 
WHERE
    A1.ServiceID = 1302
AND (C.Type LIKE '%O%' OR C.Type LIKE '%A%')
```

Can any one explain what is the use of

```
 tblA A1
    inner JOIN  tblA A2 ON A1.AcctServiceID = A2.AcctServiceID
```

and can we optimize above query? Please sugget me how to optimize the above query.

Please help me...
Thanks.

Comment: Is this the whole query?

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this. The "how to optimize bit" would not be a good question, but that's a red herring. The real question here is obviously what is going on with the self-join, which seems to be unfamiliar to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 inner JOIN  tblA A2 ON A1.AcctServiceID = A2.AcctServiceID
```

This line means you join tblA as A1 with the tblA as A2, and show line when AcctServiceID from tblA as A1 is the same as AcctServiceID from tblA as A2..
The way to optimize this query is remove this line, becouse don't do anything. AcctServiceID aways be the same as AcctSerivceID becouse is the same field.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of good reasons where you might want to join a table back to itself... but I don't see it here. Normally you need at least two join conditions, a join condition that looks for some type of inequality, or a join condition that can match zero or more than one record in the table (to increase or limit the number of results).

I don't see anything like that here. In this case, it looks like you could just remove the join, and update all references to A2 to use A1 instead. Is this the full query?

The closest thing I can think of here is that they're doing this to filter out records with NULL in the AcctServiceID field (since NULL is not equal to itself), but this would be a strange way to try that, if it even works.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see anything strange with this particular self-join. Well, not until we know more about the table, at least. At this point, I could easily imagine its meaning as *‘Get rows from `tblA` that have the same `AcctServiceID` as the row(s) with `ServiceID = 1302`’*. The resulting set could contain rows with different `ServiceID` values if `AcctServiceID` was something like a category or any other kind of attribute whose single value could be assigned to multiple rows.